# How to show single component in LayOut?

Tags: sketchup

I have woodworking project with multiple components which I would like to show in LayOut with details/dimensions(top, left, front, iso) for the engineer, who is going to actually make components from the wood. How can I place individual components into LayOut, without creating separate .skp for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

**Save Views** (and name them consistently) in **SketchUp** of each component in the correct ortho orientation (plan, section elevation) using either layers or hide to control visibility of non-focal elements for each view.

***Annotate*** and ***dimension*** appropriately: all dimensions and annotations should be *associative*, which means not only that they move and adjust with element translations, it *also* means that when the layer the dimensioned or annotated element is on is hidden, so is the relative annotation. You can also individually directly control the layers of the annotations and dimensions themselves.

Those views, with all appropriate annos & dims and set by you to the correct scale in the VIEW (not after the fact in **Layout**) are what you place on sheets in **Layout**.

The reason I mention setting correct scale in Views in **SketchUp** is that when you alter the scale in **Layout**, the impact on apparent text size for annos and dims is both large and frustrating - skip that issue by having good discipline in setting scales in the appropriate place - the saved view.

Comment: Why not annotate and set dimensions in Layout?

Comment: Makes it simpler in workflow and easier to manage relative sizing of annotative items if you have your scale set correctly and work in that SU view directly. You *can* of course do it the other way round, but I find it can get... messy.